# Splitting into multiple arrays with multiple delimiters

Tags: c#, regex, sql-server-2008

I have a text file containing name conversions between two tables in a relational database. The reason for this is that I have several huge, flat tables(non relational) which I need to split into multiple (relational) tables.

Let's assume that I have the tables: OldTable1, OldTable2, NewTable1, NewTable2, NewTable3. The old tables are not related and have different column names and number of columns.

Each text file has the name of one of the new tables (i.e. NewTable1.txt) and contains the following name conversion:

> [oldColumn1]=[newColumn1] dataType :SomeProperty :SomeAdditionalProperty
>
> ...
>
> [oldColumnN]=[newColumnN] dataType :SomeProperty :SomeAdditionalProperty

Where a line can have an arbitrary number of Someproperty and each column name has these brackets "[]" as shown above.

Either do I want to have an array or a list for:

1. old column names
2. new column names
3. data types
4. properties

OR be able to access them easily and efficiently. I have been searching the net and want to avoid the use of regular expressions if there is a way around them.

If a regular expression is inevitable what would it look like? (Remember that each line can have an arbitrary number of :Someproperty

I know I could add the contents to a single array using String.Split function with multiple delimiters and then split that one up.

Comment: I think I will solve this by splitting by multiple delimiters into a single array and then split that one up. I will have to change the form though, having it like this:

Comment: [OldColumnK]=[NewColumnK];dataType;:SomeProperty:SomeOtherPropery where 1<=K<=N. Having the first split by { "=","\r\n"} and the second by {";"}. Then every four lines go into separate arrays.